# GMap.NET in WPF, don't work Markers

Tags: c#, dictionary, gmap.net

How can I add Marker to my map?
I use:

```
PointLatLng point = gMap.FromLocalToLatLng(62.03175418653, 129.731884002686);
GMapMarker marker = new GMapMarker(point);
gMap.Markers.Add(marker);
```

it's don't work..

my gMap:

```
    gMap.MapProvider = GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
    gMap.Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
    GMapProvider.WebProxy = null;
    gMap.Position = new PointLatLng(62.03175418653, 129.731884002686);
    gMap.MinZoom = 1;
    gMap.MaxZoom = 20;
    gMap.Zoom = 10;
```

Pls Help!

Comment: I think you're supposed to add markers to an overlay, then add that overlay to your map? Not that familiar with GMap.net though. Maybe the [tutorial](http://www.websofia.com/2013/02/gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons/) here can help.

Comment: Overlays are not includeded in the WPF MapControl. You add markers using various Markers.Add methods. For example, create a route containing your points then add it as Markers using MapControl.Markers.Add(myRoute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a shape to your marker.

```
marker.Shape = new MarkerShape(....);
```