# Add Markers in WPF

Tags: wpf, gmap.net

I need to add markers to my map. Problem: I'm using WPF, not WinForms.

```
GMapMarker marker = new GMapMarker(new PointLatLng(-25.966688, 32.580528));
gmap.Markers.Add(marker);
```

Now according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831777/gmap-net-in-wpf-dont-work-markers) the solution is:

```
marker.Shape = new MarkerShape(....);
```

Could someone explain to me, how to I initalize this shape?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the problem with:

```
marker.Shape = new Ellipse
            {
                Width = 10,
                Height = 10,
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = 1.5
            };
```

That's a little black circle.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new UserControl - your own, and inside the control put a image you like (for example pin image). Note that all the events (like Click event) must be implement inside a control.

After that you can add the marker like:

```
        GMapMarker marker = new GMapMarker(new PointLatLng(##, ##));
        marker.Shape = new PinControl();
        gmap.Markers.Add(marker);
```

Comment: Any idea on how to do this using MvvM instead of random code behind?